# NRPE: Unable to read output locally

Tags: centos, nagios, nrpe

I am running `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_disk` as root yet get `NRPE: Unable to read output`.

Any help?

Comment: What does `grep check_disk /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` return (cut-and-paste into your question, please)?

Comment: After you try MadHatter's suggestion, you might want to try running the nrpe check *as the nagios user* on the remote host to make sure there are no permissions problems. 80% of the time when I get that error, its a permissions/ownership problem. You can also try the -n flag to check_nrpe to make sure that SSL is working properly. Lastly, if its not a supplied check (I write a lot of my own NRPE checks), you can get that error if the script outputs junk text. Unlikely to be the problem with check_disk, assuming it's defined in the nrpe.cfg and installed correctly.

Comment: @MadHatter `[root@1 ~]# ls /etc/nagios/nrpe.d/
nrpe-check_cpu.cfg  nrpe-check_disk.cfg  nrpe-check_load.cfg  nrpe-check_ntp_time.cfg  nrpe-check_ram.cfg  nrpe-check_swap.cfg`.

I am using puppet to manage nagios. Contents of `/etc/nagios/nrpe.d/nrpe-check_disk.cfg` are `# Configuration for check_disk (from the generic template)
command[check_disk]=/usr/libexec/nagios/plugins/check_disk -l -X binfmt_misc -X rpc_pipefs -w 5% -c 2%`

Comment: @SomeLinuxNerd I have ran this remotely and locally as nagios and on the client. Some commands return a value, some return the unable to read output.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the puppet module https://github.com/thias/puppet-nagios has a bug causing the commands to be referenced from a non existent folder `/usr/libexec/nagios/plugins/` vs `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/`.

Comment: If by "bug" you mean "that's the default path if you install Nagios/NRPE from source"

Comment: I use RPM's, not source on CentOS 6.5, so its stores in lib/lib64, rather than libexec. Puppet module wasn't using correct paths.